# BrokenFilesystemWarning in Werkzeug

Tags: python, docker, flask, encoding, utf-8

When I run my program locally, everything goes successfully, but when I run it on the docker I get:

```
resp = api_instance.import(rt_import=jsonpickle.decode(file.read()))

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

which most likely results from `BrokenFilesystemWarning`.:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/filesystem.py:63: 
BrokenFilesystemWarning: Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem: Will 
use UTF-8 as filesystem encoding instead of 'ascii' 
BrokenFilesystemWarning)
```

Am I able to fix it somehow or do I have to rummage on the server side?

Comment: I've same issue using Flask into Docker container, but with Python 3.6:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/filesystem.py:60: BrokenFilesystemWarning: Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem: Will use UTF-8 as filesystem encoding instead of 'ascii'`. I'm looking for a solutions as well. Have you got the solution?

Comment: I've solved it. In my case I was running my script in a Docker container with a different Python version (3.6.9) that I used to develop and test it (3.7.5). So, now I've installed  the same version into the container and don't get this error anymore. I hope this would be useful for others.

Comment: Thank you, I also solved it in the same way as you.